# Cross-site scripting in Classic ASP when writing javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, xss

In a server-side Classic ASP file, let's say you receive a Request string containing malicious javascript like, "`alert('HACKED');`"

```
DIM foo : foo = Request.Form("foo"); 'Contains malicious javascript
```

and then later we're writing javascript to screen containing that value.

```
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
   // some code
   <%=foo %>
   // some more code
</script>
<%
```

What do we do here keep ourselves safe against this form of cross-site scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Always remember: "Filter your input, and escape your output"

You filter data for safe storage in a database (to prevent SQL Injection), and you escape data before presenting it to the user (to prevent XSS)

Try ASP's [HTMLEncode()](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/met_htmlencode.asp) method.

Comment: But HTMLEncode() leaves the string "alert('HACKED');" unaffected?

Comment: The user will see (as literal text on the page) `alert("HACKED");` but the actual HTML will be rendered as  `alert&#40;&quot;HACKED&quot;&#41;&#59;`. No javascript `alert()` box will appear.

Comment: Single quotes do not get encoded by HTMLEncode(), and neither do the parenthesis or the semi colon. HTMLEncode() works well for HTML, and I use it all over, but in this case I'm outputting javascript not HTML.

Comment: Well that's a tough one. It would be next to impossible to determine what particular code constitutes "malicious". Can I ask why you're having your users supply you with JavaScript in the first place? Are you doing something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_text